# What is the LeTex command of this symbol?

Tags: symbols

I have encountered a symbol in section 2.2 of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.14310.pdf) paper.

[image]

Could you elaborate on the command to get this symbol? I used [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) but to no avail.

Comment: Give `\varpi` a try.

Comment: @Mico Thank you so much for your help!